# Can I dynamically call a static method in Dart?

Tags: dart

I can dynamically call a method of an instance, but I don't manage to call a static method (to save resources when an instance is not necessary).

The main idea is to code 3-4 class for courses of different level and then use the selected one (based on the user's choice).

```
class AvailablePlans {
  final _plans = [Beginner()];
  static const _staticPlans = [Beginner];

  getPlan() {
    return _plans[0];
  }

  static getStaticPlan() {
    return _staticPlans[0];
  }
}

class Beginner {
  void sayHello() {
    print('Hello world!');
  }

  void sayHelloStatic() {
    print('Hello world!');
  }
}

void main() {
  var x = AvailablePlans().getPlan();
  x.sayHello(); // print Hello world!

  var y = AvailablePlans.getStaticPlan();
  y.sayHelloStatic(); // Uncaught exception: C.Type_Beginner00_coO.sayHelloStatic$0 is not a function

}
```

Thank-you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can always introduce an interface:

```dart
abstract class Course {
  String get level;
  void sayHello();
}
```

Implement that interface:

```dart
class Beginner implements Course {
  @override
  String get level => 'beginner';

  @override
  void sayHello() {
    print('Hello from $level');
  }
}
```

You can store instances like so: `final courses = <Course>[Beginner(), Intermediate()];`

There are a couple of problems with this approach though.

> (to save resources when an instance is not necessary)

Don't worry about that. Seems like premature optimization. If you run into performance problems around instantiation of classes, you can always try optimize it later.

You wouldn't be able to look up which class instance you need by a level. So I'd create a lookup map by level:

```dart
final courseByLevel = <String, Course>{
  'beginner': Beginner(),
  'intermediate': Intermediate()
};
```

This way you get the same class instance and you can easily grab it by `courseByLevel['beginner']` expression.